# Damaged repomd.xml for mysql56-community when installing mysql

Tags: centos, mysql

I am getting an error when I try to install mysql. This error says:

```
http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.6-community/el/7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] Error importing repomd.xml for mysql56-community: Damaged repomd.xml file
```

This is the only contents of the repo file that I have:

```
# Enable to use MySQL 5.6
[mysql56-community]
name=MySQL 5.6 Community Server
baseurl=http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-5.6-community/el/7/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql
```

What is the problem and how do I correct that?

Comment: Just tested your file, this works perfectly fine on my server. Would you mind explaining what did you try ?